# Runtime error if AllowBypassKey set to false in Access Runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

**Since I put a code AllowBypassKey = false in my program**

If I run my code in Access Runtime 2010, automatically gives an Runtime Error and closes my program for no reason. :(

==================

```
What I did is : 

-The first form will show in the program is the LoginForm
-On Load LoginForm
CurrentDB.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = false


-On Click Quit Button in the LoginForm.
If txtpassword = strByPassCode then CurrentDB.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
```

====================

Im not really sure whats happening with my program
but If I run my program in Full Version Ms Access 2010
I didn't encounter any errors with my codes.

But if I remove the AllowByPassKey it will run smoothly. But I need to put
a ByPass Code so that my codes will be protected and also the tables.

Comment: This sounds like it's a problem only with the Access run-time version.  But check whether it also happens with your full Access version when you start that with the `/runtime` command-line switch.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207

Comment: @HansUp - I tried what you said. to run my accdb with /runtime but its working fine =/

Comment: OK.  Unfortunately we will not be able to replicate the problem without installing the run-time version.  But maybe someone else already has it ...

Comment: I really hate Access Runtime. But I have to forced to work with it since my client doesn't have MS Office 2010 license ! :( Thank for the help though. But I need more help! :(

Answer (score 0):

I already solve my problem.  It was a data problem 
from the clients database. I was so d**b I didn't copy
his database.

Thanks for the help :)